# Symbolic linking to ~/ instead of ~/[path/file]

Tags: symlink, dot-files

I moved all of my dot files out of
`~/` in to `~/data/dotfiles`

I then did `ln -s ~/data/dotfiles/[filename] ~/`

My intention was `ln -s ~/data/dotfiles/[filename] ~/[filename]`

This included my `.vimrc` , `.bashrc` And others

Now when I open a terminal session or open vim I get `too many levels of symbolic links.`

I'm unsure if I delete the symbolic link from my home directory or from the directory the files live in.

Any help would be appreciated.

As per request:
`jsw:dotfiles jsw$ ls -l ~/.vimrc ~/data/dotfiles/.vimrc
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jsw  staff      6  1 Aug 13:54 /Users/jsw/.vimrc -> .vimrc
-rw-r--r--  1 jsw  staff  11044 31 Jul 10:51 /Users/jsw/data/dotfiles/.vimrc`

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `ls -l ~/.vimrc ~/data/dotfiles/.vimrc` ?

Comment: @frostschutz if you are asking why I want to remove the links it's because I made a mistake and given I'm getting too many levels of symbolic links I need to resolve the issue. If you are referring to why I'd want to move my dotfiles out of my home directory in the first place and then link them back it's because I was putting them into a git repo to prepare for setting up another machine.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Updated my question with the result. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> lrwxr-xr-x  1 jsw  staff      6  1 Aug 13:54 /Users/jsw/.vimrc -> .vimrc

You've made a mistake; this was produced by the equivalent of:

```
ln -s .vimrc .vimrc
```

You could have done something more convoluted than that (`ln -s foo/../.vimrc .vimrc`), but in any case, as long as there isn't an actual `.vimrc` file, `ln` will create the link, but it will be a dud.  If you try and access it you will get:

```
foobar: ./.vimrc:
Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Where "foobar" is the name of the application that tried the access. Just delete the link and try again.  Besides `ls`, `stat .vimrc` will show you what a file points to.   The output for this one would start:

```
File: ‘.vimrc’ -> ‘.vimrc’
```

Whoops!  `readlink` is even simpler:

```
> readlink .vimrc
.vimrc
```

Giving just the path the link points to.  If that's the exact same path as the file, it's a circular link.  You want to see:

```
> readlink .vimrc
data/dotfiles/.vimrc
```